# Static network want to add guest dhcp router

Tags: routing, dhcp, static-ip

My work would like me to add a guest wireless for our customers. The problem I have is the system they have set up is all static ip's.

How can I add a wireless router to the network so guests can connect and use the Internet?

I am fairly new at all this so easier is better ;). Thanks!

Edit: could I just use this?  Will it work?
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0ED-0005-00019

Answer (score 0):

Static IPs are irrelevant.  You can give guests DHCP addresses (via the WAP or your network hardware) on a different subnet with access only to the Internet.  That being said, any wireless access point will do, as long as it is connected to a secured port on your network.  As for which product, we cant help you with that.  Obviously, the size of the area you want to cover will affect the model and price.  Security features will also play a factor, but you didnt list any requirements.

Comment: There are multiple rooms but we are going to start with one that is about 100 x 50 feet. All open.   Is there a tutorial you can point me to as I do not know how to,set up. A subnet or what a secured port is ;).